# How to query "Main Window" in iOS UI tests?

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcuitest

At one point in my tests I need to interact with views that are inside `Main Window`. When I do a `po app.windows`, I get this:

```
Find: Target Application 0x1c40d7680
  Output: {
    Application, 0x1c4389170, pid: 4765, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: 'Mercedes PRO [testb2b]'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Window
    Output: {
      Window, 0x1c43890a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window, 0x1c438dc30, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window, 0x1c438dea0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
      Window, 0x1c438e6c0, Main Window, {{0.0, 0.5}, {375.0, 667.0}}
    }
```

I need to query `Main Window` since I have almost the same views in the first Window from this list, so I want to separate them. So, I tried querying it with `app.windows["Main Window"]`, but it seems like `Main Window` is not an identifier for a window view.

Printing all [XCUIElementAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes) (like `title`, `value`, `identifier` and so on) didn't give me much information (they are mainly empty strings). Also, I don't want to query it by position (like this: `app.windows.element(boundBy: 3)`) since I'm not sure if this Window will always be at this position.

Is there another way to query `Main Window`?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @osrl No, not yet, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to achieve is to put an identifier to the window object. I tried adding it in the ViewController that shows views I'm trying to query with this line of code (in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.accessibilityIdentifier = "Main Window"
```

And I kept getting identifier in the wrong place:

```
Find: Target Application 0x60c0000c1260
  Output: {
    Application, 0x60c00018c640, pid: 33496, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: '[testb2b]'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Window
    Output: {
      Window, 0x60c00018c710, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, identifier: 'Main Window'
      Window, 0x60c000191370, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Window, 0x60c0001915e0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Window, 0x60c000191c60, Main Window, {{0.0, 0.5}, {414.0, 736.0}}
    }
```

Then I found a place in the code where developers created a new window that they used to hold that VC.

```
let actionVC = UIStoryboard.findViewController(withIdentifier: "ActionViewController")
if let appWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
     let window = UIWindow.init(frame: appWindow.frame)
     window.rootViewController = actionVC
     window.accessibilityIdentifier = "Main Window"
}
```

This allowed me to write a query like this: `app.windows["Main Window"]` and to be sure that I'm targeting the real `Main Window`.

```
Find: Target Application 0x60c0000c1260
  Output: {
    Application, 0x60c00018c640, pid: 33496, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: '[testb2b]'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Window
    Output: {
      Window, 0x60c00018c710, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Window, 0x60c000191370, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Window, 0x60c0001915e0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Window, 0x60c000191c60, Main Window, {{0.0, 0.5}, {414.0, 736.0}}, identifier: 'Main Window'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found was filtering the windows using their frame size.

```
let window = app.windows.allElementsBoundByIndex.first { element in
                element.frame.width > 10
            }!
```

I will edit this if I find a better way.

Comment: This solution won't work. In this case (since the width of all 4 windows in the list is always greater than 10; you can see it in the logs), this is essentially the same as writing this `app.windows.element(boundBy: 0)`. And I want to avoid using that method. What would work in this situation is this condition (since `Main Window`'s origins are `{0.0, 0.5}`): `element.frame.origin.y > 0`.
I still didn't have problems with relying on finding window element by index, so I may leave my solution untouched.

Comment: Yes you are right. My windows' sizes were 0x0 or 2x2. So that worked for me. I know that's not a good solution thoug